# Usar constantes globales provenientes de un servicio REST desde MySql en Angular

Tags: angular

Estoy usando un archivo de constantes para usar en todos mis componentes, pero me solicitan que esa información pueda provenir de una BBDD de Mysql. Sé cómo usar un servicio REST pero no sé cómo transformar la información recibida en valores para cada elemento de la clase Constantes. Mi clase es del tipo model:

```
 export class Constantes {
    public static API_SERVER = 'http://rutaservidor.com/APIREST'; //necesito recoger este valor de MySQL
 }
```

Debería probar algo así? cómo convierto cada elemento de la consulta en una funcion estatica? algo se me escapa.

```
   this.ServicioREST.getPersona ( variable )
    .subscribe( (respuesta:ModeloDatos) => {
       this.registro = respuesta;
       public static API_SERVER = 'http://rutaservidor.com/APIREST'; //AQUÍ ME FALLA
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Crear un servicio y en su constructor hacer una petición a la API para obtener los valores que se guardarán en Constantes.
2. Inyectar el servicio en componente principal de la app (AppComponent)

**constantes.ts**

```
export class Constantes{

  public static SERVER_API:string;

}
```

**constantes.servicio.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Constantes} from './constantes';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ConstantesServicio {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
    // hacer una petición en el constructor del servicio
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/1')
    .subscribe((respuesta: any) =>{
        // inicializar las variables de la clase Constante
        Constantes.SERVER_API = respuesta.url;

        console.log("constantes inicializadas");

        console.log(Constantes.SERVER_API);

    });
   }

}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

import {ConstantesServicio}from './constantes.servicio';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  // inyectar servicio para que llame a su constructor e inicialice las variables
  constructor(private constantesServicio:ConstantesServicio){}

}
```

[Ejemplo stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xth2vu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fconstantes.servicio.ts)

Comment: No me he explicado, perdón. Sé cómo debo llamar a las constantes desde otro componente. Lo que necesito es "rellenar" las constantes en origen, es decir la clase Constantes

Comment: Comprendo. Para confirmar, primero se hará una petición REST a una API para recuperar los datos que se guardarán en la clase Constantes?

Comment: Correcto, se hace petición REST al servidor, se lee la tabla "constantes" y se recogen dichas constantes dentro del model de la clase Constantes. Algo como  public static API_SERVER = lo que recojo de esa API

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: No entiendo lo del app.module.ts, quisiste decir app.component.ts?

Comment: Lo he probado y el modelo "Constantes" no me lee el servicio

Comment: Sí, es el app.component. Corregí el ejemplo de stackblitz. Constantes no lee el servicio, el servicio asigna los valores a Constantes. Después de eso Constantes puede usarse en toda la aplicación.